# Localization based on URL .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to get view localization based on the url instead of browser culture.

**"/account/leadregistrationstep/de"** Will display the view without translation. To get the translation the browser culture must match with the view (this works).

Is there a way to get the translation without having the browser culture need to match the resource file?  I want the german view to display only german language

[image]

**Startup ConfigureServices**

```
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("de"),
                    new CultureInfo("nl"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr")
                };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "nl", uiCulture: "nl");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider());
            });
```

**Configure**

```
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{language}/{id?}");
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three default RequestCultureProviders, among them is: AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider which use the browser headers for the culture info. You need to overwrite the list instead of inserting the QueryStringRequestCultureProvider into it, thus removing the AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider.

```
options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
        {
            new CultureInfo("en"),
            new CultureInfo("de"),
            new CultureInfo("nl"),
            new CultureInfo("fr")
        };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "nl", uiCulture: "nl");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
        {
            new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
            new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
        };
    }
```

That will use only a set cookie, or the querystring ?culture=fr ... to select the culture.

However if you need custom rules, you need to implement your own RequestCultureProvider. This is an example:

```
public class UrlRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var validCultures = new []{"en", "de", "fr", "nl"};
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
        }

        var culture = httpContext.Request.Path.Value
                        .Split("/")
                        .FirstOrDefault( (p) => validCultures.IndexOf(p.ToLower()) >= 0);

        if (culture == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult((ProviderCultureResult)null);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(culture));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the correct way to do this ? Do i need a specific class that deals with this ?

Comment: If you need custom rules, then you need to implement your own RequestCultureProvider, but if you only want to use the QueryStringRequestCultureProvider - then the code I posted should suffice.

Comment: ?culture=fr ... is the querystring way

Comment: Oh my bad. That worked with my code as well.. I'm looking for a solution where i dont need to pass the culture. The culture should be the language of the view so 

/de should only display german etc..